# Assimp importer cleanup with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, assimp

I'm trying to import some animation files with Assimp and add them to a list of existing animations. However I'm having trouble with the aiAnimation->mChannels (type aiNodeAnim**) in that when my function returns, my new aiAnimation object's mChannels pointer is invalid. This is because Assimp's Importer cleans up after itself when it is destroyed. What I need is to copy the channels such that they are not deleted when the importer goes out of scope.

This is my animation appending function as it stands, which updates as I would expect but produces a runtime exception "Engine.exe has triggered a breakpoint" when returning from the function.

```
void Animation::AddAnimation(const char* p_filePath)
{
    Assimp::Importer m_importer;
    const aiScene* m_scene = m_importer.ReadFile(p_filePath,
        aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace |
        aiProcess_Triangulate |
        aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
        aiProcess_SortByPType | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals);


    for (int i = 0; i < m_scene->mNumAnimations; ++i)
    {
        aiAnimation* m_newAnimation = new aiAnimation(*m_scene->mAnimations[i]);
        m_newAnimation->mName = m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mName;
        m_newAnimation->mDuration = m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mDuration;
        m_newAnimation->mTicksPerSecond = m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mTicksPerSecond;
        m_newAnimation->mNumChannels = m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mNumChannels;
        if (m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mChannels != NULL)
        {
            aiNodeAnim* m_channels = *m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mChannels;
            *m_newAnimation->mChannels = new aiNodeAnim[m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mNumChannels];
            for (int j = 0; j < m_scene->mAnimations[i]->mNumChannels; ++j)
            {
                m_newAnimation->mChannels[j] = new aiNodeAnim();
                m_newAnimation->mChannels[j] = &m_channels[j];
            }
        }
        g_channels = m_newAnimation->mChannels;
        g_animations.push_back(m_newAnimation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please step through with a debugger, before asking.

Comment: Unfortunately debugging doesn't yield any additional information about the error. To be honest I'm not even sure copying each item individually is even the right way to go, if I could copy the entire array in memory instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but are you asking if you need to copy the animation channels *individually*? The answer to that is yes, because you can't be sure that they will be contiguous in memory if you tried to do a `memcpy` of the array of `m_channels`, or even of each entry in the array. You'll have to copy each of the arrays of rotation, translation, and scaling keys manually.

By the way, these lines of code

```
m_newAnimation->mChannels[j] = new aiNodeAnim();
m_newAnimation->mChannels[j] = &m_channels[j];
```

Probably do not do what you intend. In the first line, you allocate space and initialize a new animation and in the second line you blow it away with the address of the importer's channel. Removing the second line and copying the contents of the aiNodeAnim into your array would fix this.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that bit out a while ago. What I'm doing now is creating a wrapper class for the assimp aiAnimations and doing a deep copy of everything, using smart pointers to pass around ownership, rather than the 'new' operator. I've not completed that (yet) as I've had the project on pause for a couple of weeks, but I'll be continuing with that technique when I resume